# In a tabbed form showing/hiding tabs not executing propperly (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create a tabbed form for login and registration in my form. However, the javascript I am using to hide/show the containers are not working.
I have used document.getElementById to turn my containers into local variables. And the tab button executes the function to show the needed tab and hide the other tab onclick().
By default, in CSS I wrote code so that the login tab would be visible. I can't find where the problem is
p.s. registration form is a bit bulky

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
var logBox = document.getElementById("logbox");
var regBox = document.getElementById("regbox");
var loginTab = document.getElementById("lt");
var regTab = document.getElementById("rt");
  }

function regTabFun(){
event.preventDefault();
regBox.style.visibility="visible";
logBox.style.visibility="hidden";
forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";
}



function loginTabFun(){
event.preventDefault();
regBox.style.visibility="hidden";
loginBox.style.visibility="visible";
forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

```css
.comm {
  margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
#logbox {
visibility: visible;
}
#regbox {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="logTabFun()"style="color: #AE20EC; font-size: x-large;">Sign-in Form</p>
    <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()" style="color: #AE20EC; font-size: x-large;">Sign-up Form</p>
    
    <div id="regbox" class="comm">

    <section id="innerbox">
        
        <section id="names">
            <!--use proper tags-->
            <section id="fn">
            <label for="name">
               <b>First Name:</b>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
        </section>
        <section id="n">
            <label for="surname">
               <b>Last Name:</b>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname"></section>
        </section>
        <B>Username:</B><input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <B>Email:</B><input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
        <B>Telephone Number:</B><input type="tel" name="Telephone Number" id="tel">
        <B id="DoB">Date of Birth:</B><input type="date" name="Date of Birth" id="dob">
        <B>Password:</B><input type="password" name="Password" id="pass">
        <input id="btn" type="button" onclick="register()" value="submit">
    </section>
</div>


<div id="logbox" class="comm">
  <section id="innerbox">
      
      </section>
  <B>Username:</B><input type="text" name="usernmae" id="username">
      <B>Password:</B><input type="password" name="Password" id="pass">
      <input id="btn" type="button"  onclick="login()" value="submit">
      <p onclick="forTabFun()">Forgot Password?</p>
```

Comment: Your snippet results in a series of errors, like `login is not defined`,  `regTabFun is not defined`, and `logTabFun is not defined`. Make sure to name your variables and functions properly and reference them correctly.

Comment: Use your browser’s dev tools inspect facility and look for any errors, of which there are quite a few, on its console. If you are still stuck put the corrected code into your question so we can help.

Comment: I corrected the names of my variables and functions. Turns out there were typos, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the incorrect variable and function names. The corrected code is below:

```js
var logBox = document.getElementById("logbox");
var regBox = document.getElementById("regbox");
var forgetBox = document.getElementById("forgot");
var logTab = document.getElementById("lt");
var regTab = document.getElementById("rt");

function regTabFun(){
event.preventDefault();
regBox.style.visibility="visible";
logBox.style.visibility="hidden";
forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";
}

function logTabFun(){
event.preventDefault();
regBox.style.visibility="hidden";
logBox.style.visibility="visible";
forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";
}
function forTabFun(){
event.preventDefault();
regBox.style.visibility="hidden";
logBox.style.visibility="hidden";
forgetBox.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

```css
.comm {
  margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
#logbox {
visibility: visible;
}
#regbox {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="logTabFun()"style="color: #AE20EC; font-size: x-large;">Sign-in Form</p>
    <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()" style="color: #AE20EC; font-size: x-large;">Sign-up Form</p>
    
    <div id="regbox" class="comm">

    <section id="innerbox">
        
        <section id="names">
            <!--use proper tags-->
            <section id="fn">
            <label for="name">
               <b>First Name:</b>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
        </section>
        <section id="n">
            <label for="surname">
               <b>Last Name:</b>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname"></section>
        </section>
        <B>Username:</B><input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <B>Email:</B><input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
        <B>Telephone Number:</B><input type="tel" name="Telephone Number" id="tel">
        <B id="DoB">Date of Birth:</B><input type="date" name="Date of Birth" id="dob">
        <B>Password:</B><input type="password" name="Password" id="pass">
        <input id="btn" type="button" onclick="register()" value="submit">
    </section>
</div>


<div id="logbox" class="comm">
  <section id="innerbox">
      
      </section>
  <B>Username:</B><input type="text" name="usernmae" id="username">
      <B>Password:</B><input type="password" name="Password" id="pass">
      <input id="btn" type="button"  onclick="login()" value="submit">
      <p onclick="forTabFun()">Forgot Password?</p>

<div id="forgot" class="comm">
  <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
  <div>
    <B>Email:</B>
  <input id="email" type="email" required/>
  <input id="btn" type="button"  onclick="forgot()" value="submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works pretty well, actually. Good for my beginner level website!